# Suspicious series of downvotes

Tags: support

Today I became a victim of several (uncommented) downvotes, 6 posts got downvote. I suspect this was happening for personal reasons only. My question is now how to deal with that. It is clear that I never will get any response if I just ask about the downvotes in the comment section of the questions/answer in question. Ignore? And is there a mechanism to undo this  loss of reputation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your questions are covered by the Stack Exchange FAQ:

[What do I do if I suspect someone has downvoted a lot of my posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93142/194636)

and

[I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121350/194636)

and in the Help Centre:

[Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says "voting corrected"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

---

I would say the best thing you can do is to *improve the quality of your questions and answers*.

By the way, I would also encourage you to avoid:

- Asking for upvotes in comments
- Unnecessary minor edits to your posts
- Repeatedly unaccepting/accepting answers

These actions are just noise, and may even be encouraging the votes you are complaining about.